# HAProxy seems to be load balancing instead of following ACL rules

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy, access-control-list

I'm seeing some really odd behavior with HAProxy. I have the following setup below designed to allow example.com/wiki to go to one server and example.com/ go to another. The trouble is that it seems like the /wiki only works half the time and the / webserver only works half the time as well. Upon closer examination, it seems like it's switching between the two backends; possibly load balancing them, instead of going to a specific backend based on the ACL rules!

Another oddity is that both services-staging.example.com/greenoven and staging.example.com both would go to kumquat, even though the rules specifically say that only the services-staging host should go to that backend.

Is something wrong with my HAProxy configuration? Am I using acls or backends incorrectly?

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 debug
        maxconn 200000
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        #debug
        #quiet

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        maxconn 200000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

        stats uri /monitor
        stats auth admin:GS01
        stats refresh 5s
        stats enable


frontend http-in
        bind *:80

        option forwardfor

        #Staging Hosts

        acl host_staging hdr(host) -i staging.example.com
        acl host_staging_services hdr(host) -i staging-services.example.com

        #Production Hosts

        acl host_prod hdr(host) -i example.com www.example.com
        acl host_prod_services hdr(host) -i services.urbanatla.com

        #URL Paths

        acl url_wiki url_beg /wiki
        acl url_go   url_beg /greenoven
        acl url_arcgis url_beg /ArcGIS

        #Staging Backends

        use_backend pluto if host_staging_services url_arcgis
        use_backend kumquat if host_staging_services url_go
        use_backend kumquat if host_staging url_wiki
        use_backend cumberland if host_staging

        #Production Backends

        use_backend saturn if host_prod_services url_arcgis
        use_backend willow if host_prod_services url_go
        use_backend willow if host_prod url_wiki
        use_backend ganges if host_prod


backend kumquat
        server kumquat kumquat.example.com:8080 maxconn 5000

backend cumberland
        server cumberland cumberland.example.com:80 maxconn 5000

backend ganges
        server ganges ganges.example.com:80 maxconn 5000

backend articdata
        server articdata  articdata.example.com:80 maxconn  5000

backend saturn
        server saturn saturn.example.com:80 maxconn 5000

backend willow
        server willow willow.example.com:8080 maxconn 5000

backend pluto
        server pluto pluto.example.com:80 maxconn 5000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it was reusing connections, which you shouldn't do when you're doing context switching. I added the following:

```
option httpclose
```

per this post: [Why am I getting errors in my HAProxy content switching config?](https://serverfault.com/questions/104350/why-am-i-getting-errors-in-my-haproxy-content-switching-config).

All URLs and domains work correctly now.

Comment: I'd suggest using "option http-server-close" instead, so that you still have keep-alive enabled on the client side of the connection. Since the client side is the one with the higher latency, it gives you a big advantage.

Answer (score 1):

If you read in the haproxy [documentation](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt), you can find this paragraph:

```
hdr(name)   The HTTP header <name> will be looked up in each HTTP request.
            Just as with the equivalent ACL 'hdr()' function, the header
            name in parenthesis is not case sensitive. If the header is
            absent or if it does not contain any value, the roundrobin
            algorithm is applied instead.
```

This can explain why haproxy is doing load balancing between servers not following the ACLs. To make sure, you need to check that you are really getting the request with `host` header.

I think you can use the destination IP, name, or URL instead of checking the `host` header.

Comment: My hdr() functions seem to be working correctly for production. I'm only calling the services by their hostnames, never IP, so the host header is always populated. It's the URLs that seem to be screwy. I tried changing the url_beg to path_beg and am having the same issues.