# HAProxy high CPU usage - configuration issue?

Tags: haproxy

We recently had a spike in traffic, which while only moderate in size, caused haproxy to max out one of the CPU cores (and the server became unresponsive).  I'm guessing that I'm doing something inefficiently the config, and so would like to ask all the haproxy experts out there if they would be so kind as to critique my config file below (mainly from a performance perspective).

The config is intended to distribute between a group of http-application servers, a group of servers that handle websockets connections (with a number of seperate processes on different ports), and a static file webserver.  It's working well appart from the performance issue. (Some details have been redacted.)

Any guidance you could offer would be much appreciated!

HAProxy v1.4.8

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
        global
                daemon
                maxconn         100000
                log             127.0.0.1 local0 notice
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
        defaults
                log                     global
                mode                    http
                option                  httplog
                option                  httpclose               #http://serverfault.com/a/104782/52811
                timeout connect         5000ms
                timeout client          50000ms
                timeout server          5h                      #long timeouts to stop WS drops - when v1.5 is stable, use 'timeout tunnel';
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# FRONTEND
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
        frontend public
                bind *:80
                maxconn         100000
                reqidel ^X-Forwarded-For:.*                     #Remove any x-forwarded-for headers
                option forwardfor                               #Set the forwarded for header (needs option httpclose)

                default_backend app
                redirect prefix http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }
                timeout client  5h                              #long timeouts to stop WS drops - when v1.5 is stable, use 'timeout tunnel';

        # ACLs
        ##########
        acl static_request hdr_beg(host) -i i.
        acl static_request hdr_beg(host) -i static.
        acl static_request path_beg /favicon.ico /robots.txt
        acl test_request hdr_beg(host) -i test.
        acl ws_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws
        # ws11
        acl ws11x1_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws11x1
        acl ws11x2_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws11x2
        acl ws11x3_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws11x3
        acl ws11x4_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws11x4
        acl ws11x5_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws11x5
        acl ws11x6_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws11x6
        # ws12
        acl ws12x1_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws12x1
        acl ws12x2_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws12x2
        acl ws12x3_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws12x3
        acl ws12x4_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws12x4
        acl ws12x5_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws12x5
        acl ws12x6_request hdr_beg(host) -i ws12x6

        # Which backend....
        ###################
        use_backend static   if static_request
        #ws11
        use_backend ws11x1 if ws11x1_request
        use_backend ws11x2 if ws11x2_request
        use_backend ws11x3 if ws11x3_request
        use_backend ws11x4 if ws11x4_request
        use_backend ws11x5 if ws11x5_request
        use_backend ws11x6 if ws11x6_request
        #ws12
        use_backend ws12x1 if ws12x1_request
        use_backend ws12x2 if ws12x2_request
        use_backend ws12x3 if ws12x3_request
        use_backend ws12x4 if ws12x4_request
        use_backend ws12x5 if ws12x5_request
        use_backend ws12x6 if ws12x6_request
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# BACKEND - APP
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
        backend app
                timeout server          50000ms #To counter the WS default
                mode http
                balance roundrobin
                option httpchk HEAD /upchk.txt
                server app1 app1:8000             maxconn 100000 check
                server app2 app2:8000             maxconn 100000 check
                server app3 app3:8000             maxconn 100000 check
                server app4 app4:8000             maxconn 100000 check
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# BACKENDs - WS
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#Server ws11
        backend ws11x1
                server ws11 ws11:8001 maxconn 100000
        backend ws11x2
                server ws11 ws11:8002 maxconn 100000
        backend ws11x3
                server ws11 ws11:8003 maxconn 100000
        backend ws11x4
                server ws11 ws11:8004 maxconn 100000
        backend ws11x5
                server ws11 ws11:8005 maxconn 100000
        backend ws11x6
                server ws11 ws11:8006 maxconn 100000
#Server ws12
        backend ws12x1
                server ws12 ws12:8001 maxconn 100000
        backend ws12x2
                server ws12 ws12:8002 maxconn 100000
        backend ws12x3
                server ws12 ws12:8003 maxconn 100000
        backend ws12x4
                server ws12 ws12:8004 maxconn 100000
        backend ws12x5
                server ws12 ws12:8005 maxconn 100000
        backend ws12x6
                server ws12 ws12:8006 maxconn 100000
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# BACKEND - STATIC
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
        backend static
                server static1 static1:80   maxconn 40000
```

Comment: I think it's not very nice to block vpns IF it's a public site.

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin - That's a long story which I don't want to get into here.

Comment: It could be due to syncookies.

Answer (score 5):

100,000 connections is a lot... Are you pushing that much? If so... maybe splitting the frontend such that it binds on one ip for static content and one ip for app content and then run the static and app variants as separate haproxy processes (assuming you have a second core / cpu on the server)...

If nothing else it will narrow the usage down to the app or static flows...

---

If I'm remembering my networking 101 class correctly... HaProxy shouldn't be able to hit `100,000` connections to `ws12:8001` or any other backend host:port because of the ~65536 port limit which is closer to `28232` on most systems (`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`). You may be exhausting the local ports which could in turn cause the cpu to hang as it waits for ports to free up.

Perhaps lowering the max connections to each backend to closer to 28000 would alleviate the problem? Or changing the local port range to be more inclusive?

Comment: Splitting into two processes is an interesting idea that I had not considered, thank you.  Static traffic is very low, as we are behind a CDN, however spitting http app calls and the websocket traffic might be worth taking a look at.  I suppose it would complicate our DNS records a little bit, but not a big deal.  I'd like to see if I'm doing anything terribly wrong with the config first, but will certainly consider this.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at nbproc setting and see if that helps by utilizing more then one core. For most hardware load balancers the amount of traffic you can handle is capped by your cpu/memory of the load balancer.

```
1.5) Increasing the overall processing power
--------------------------------------------
On multi-processor systems, it may seem to be a shame to use only one processor,
eventhough the load needed to saturate a recent processor is far above common
usage. Anyway, for very specific needs, the proxy can start several processes
between which the operating system will spread the incoming connections. The
number of processes is controlled by the 'nbproc' parameter in the 'global'
section. It defaults to 1, and obviously works only in 'daemon' mode. One
typical usage of this parameter has been to workaround the default per-process
file-descriptor limit that Solaris imposes to user processes.

Example :
---------

    global
        daemon
        quiet
        nbproc  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Outside of the configuration of haproxy it would help to do some network tuning.

One specific thing that may help is ensuring your network interfaces aren't pinned to a single CPU (assuming you are using multiple interfaces).  If you are running haproxy on Linux you can check the balance like so:

```
egrep CPU\|eth /proc/interrupts
```

For example, this shows that the interrupts for eth0 and eth1 are being handled by different CPUs:

```
$ egrep CPU\|eth /proc/interrupts
      CPU0        CPU1        CPU2    CPU3
103:  3515635238  0           0       0          IR-PCI-MSI-edge  eth0
104:  0           1976927064  0       0          IR-PCI-MSI-edge  eth1
```

Whereas this shows them being handled by the same CPU:

```
$ egrep CPU\|eth /proc/interrupts
      CPU0        CPU1  CPU2  CPU3
272:  1526254507  0     0     0     Dynamic-irq  eth0
273:  4877925     0     0     0     Dynamic-irq  eth1
```

You will want to enable smp affinity for these interfaces.  For the example above you can do the following:

```
echo 010 > /proc/irq/272/smp_affinity
echo 010 > /proc/irq/273/smp_affinity
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest activate "Multi-thread mode" by putting nbthread option to global section. From man:

> This setting is only available when support for threads was built in.
>   It creates  threads for each created processes. It means if
>   HAProxy is started in foreground, it only creates  threads for
>   the first process

We activated "Multi-thread mode" and our web-site starts to work on x15 faster. You can read more about multi-process and multi-threads option here: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/multithreading-in-haproxy/

Comment: Giving HAProxy more threads is unlikely to reduce CPU usage.